# Can't exclude monorepo package from Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, monorepo

I have a ts monorepo with the following structure:

```
/root
--/packages
----/frontend
------/src
------/public
----/api
```

I run the frontend by using `react-app-rewired`

And in my config-overrides I have:

```
const paths = require('react-scripts/config/paths')
const path = require('path')

paths.appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/packages/frontend')
paths.appIndexJs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/packages/frontend/src/index.tsx')
paths.appPublic = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/packages/frontend/public')
paths.appHtml = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/packages/frontend/public/index.html')
```

The frontend runs perfectly. The only problem is that Webpack is loading `.ts` files from the other packages, showing some errors.

I tried excluding these packages from Webpack through the `config-overrides.js` file with:

```
const { override } = require("customize-cra");
const fs = require('fs');

const excludeFromTsLoader = (excludeDirs) => (config) => {

  const excludePaths = excludeDirs.map((dir) => fs.realpathSync(path.resolve(__dirname, dir)));

  config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
    if (rule.oneOf) {
      rule.oneOf = rule.oneOf.map(oneOfRule => {
        if (oneOfRule.test && /\.(ts|tsx)$/.test(oneOfRule.test.toString())) {
          return {
            ...oneOfRule,
            include: oneOfRule.include.filter(
              includePath => !excludePaths.includes(fs.realpathSync(includePath))
            ),
          };
        }
        return oneOfRule;
      });
    }
    return rule;
  });

  return config;
};

module.exports = override(
  excludeFromTsLoader(['src/packages/api']) 
);
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Webpack should only load files required by the dependency tree from your entry points. What exactly are the errors you're seeing and what actions are you performing to produce them?